# Adding Digital Signature to an XML Document - Error Bad UID

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature, xml-signature

I'm trying a digital signature to xml file. This code is running asynchronous

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

When the code run a time then output exception:

```
javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: java.security.SignatureException: Bad UID.

at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod.sign(DOMSignatureMethod.java:345)
at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:405)
at com.chubb.util.XMLSignerUtil.signXMLContent(XMLSignerUtil.java:173)
at com.chubb.util.XMLSignerUtil.signFile(XMLSignerUtil.java:187)
at com.chubb.face.INVPanelXml$SignWorker.signContract(INVPanelXml.java:396)
at com.chubb.face.INVPanelXml$SignWorker.run(INVPanelXml.java:362)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Bad UID.

```
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CSignature.signHash(Native Method)
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CSignature$RSA.engineSign(CSignature.java:220)
at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1403)
at java.base/java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:712)
at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod.sign(DOMSignatureMethod.java:343)
... 8 more
```

java.security.SignatureException: Bad UID.

```
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CSignature.signHash(Native Method)
at jdk.crypto.mscapi/sun.security.mscapi.CSignature$RSA.engineSign(CSignature.java:220)
at java.base/java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Signature.java:1403)
at java.base/java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:712)
at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMSignatureMethod.sign(DOMSignatureMethod.java:343)
at java.xml.crypto/org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(DOMXMLSignature.java:405)
at com.chubb.util.XMLSignerUtil.signXMLContent(XMLSignerUtil.java:173)
at com.chubb.util.XMLSignerUtil.signFile(XMLSignerUtil.java:187)
at com.chubb.face.INVPanelXml$SignWorker.signContract(INVPanelXml.java:396)
at com.chubb.face.INVPanelXml$SignWorker.run(INVPanelXml.java:362)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a configuration and signature type whether you may do parallel signing. For example you need to ensure that all signatures you create are using different XML Identifiers. Otherwise there will be ambiguity for a validator to extract the validation information, and it will produce broken signatures. Also the parallel signing is not supported for enveloping or detached signature types, as the signature is being created on a root level of an XML document.
Additionally, when doing an enveloped signature, you need to ensure you are using an XPath expression excluding the current signature only from the XML scope, therefore you shall not use *http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature* to create parallel signatures.

Are you able to correctly create a single signature? If the answer is yes, then more likely the signature type you have chosen does not support parallel signing or there is a configuration problem on some step.

Comment: Yes, I can create a single signature correctly and I have been using XML Transform.ENVELOPED. Let me try to check my code!

Comment: The Transform.ENVELOPED is not suitable for parallel signing. When applying this transform, it excludes ONLY the current signature node from the scope for digest computation. So when you add a new signature to the document, it impacts the validation of existing signature, as the new signature node is not being removed after that transformation.

Comment: What you want to do is to remove ALL signature nodes from the reference digest computation in order to have valid multiple signatures within a single XML document.
To achieve it you will need to use another transform instead of Transform.ENVELOPED. It can be done using an XPath or XPath-Filter 2 transform.
For example for XPath, the Transform node would look like:
`<ds:XPath xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">not(ancestor-or-self::ds:Signature)</ds:XPath>`
This will remove all ds:Signature nodes, including the current signature node from the digest computation.